# Which latest version of python is supported by Robot Framework RIDE?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework RIDE. I had installed python 3.4 in my windows machine and then successfully installed robot framework using pip command. However I am unable to install RIDE, I am getting exception. It seems RIDE is not supported for python 3.

Is there any official site from where I can get info that which is the latest version of python that RIDE supports? Which might be updating as per new releases as we in case of Selenium on http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/. I visited the below site, but didn't got the info, searched on google as well, but it seems info on this area are lacking

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-ride

https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE

Kind Regards, Shoaib

Comment: You don't need RIDE to learn or use robot. I recommend using a plain text editor that supports robot. There are many that are mentioned on the robot website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIDE Does not yet support version 3, and runs only on the regular Python, not on Jython nor IronPython. Python 2.6 is the minimum version needed. [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions) Explains all,Go through it.

Comment: I just tried to install RIDE on python 2.7 and I am able to successfully install it(I had to install wxPython2.8 as well). So I wanted to know is there any official site where I can get these info what version of python one should use for latest version of RIDE?

Comment: So far as i told you above,its the Installation Instructions page,,where they stated that you can use any python version not less than v2.6 for any RIDE version and Only wxPython 2.8 with Unicode support is officially supported.I don't no what else details you want that is not in that page,,sorry for not being able to help with what you want.

Comment: So in short currently RIDE will supported for new version python 2.x(above 2.6) but not any new release of python 3.x(above 3.0) as of now?

Comment: exactly,,until when v3 support comes in the future,of which you will be notified on that page,,only v2.6 will have full support till then.